# iOS App reward referrals using Expo and Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, expo

I am working on an iOS app using Expo (React Native) and Firebase. We want to offer referral rewards to users who get others to download the app. Right now, we simply have a "Who told you about us" section when creating an account, but we'd like to be able to send out a referral code with the invite and track whether that user downloads the app, as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral#ios-swift_3). Unfortunately, I can't seem to find how to do this with Expo specifically. I'd love some help with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many tools that provide this kind of feature have react native SDKs, but so far I haven't found any that provides support for Expo. The tools that I found most interesting are:

**Appsflyer**: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001237818-Mobile-web-to-app-attribution-solutions

**Getsocial**: https://www.getsocial.im/use-case/build-referral-campaigns/

**Branch**: https://branch.io/referral/

But while reading the documentations, it seems that for now to have access to this type of feature it is required to eject from Expo. The "good news" is that Expo will release support for arbitrary native plugins sometime this year (source: https://forums.expo.io/t/appsflyer-integration-with-expo/32589/6).